# Enemy AI not working

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, unity-game-engine

I have recently decided to write my own AI to make a guard in a prison game walk forward and backwards. It's important to note that he walks right then left and repeats. I have a while loop that sets his coordinates and switches between public void functions, but it doesn't seem to be working: the guard just walks in one direction forever.

There are also other errors so I need an expert who can fix this if you get what I'm trying to do. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class enemyAI : MonoBehaviour 
{

private float rightDistance;
private float leftDistance;

public void moveRight(float rightDistance)
{
    rightDistance = 0.02f;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + rightDistance, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}

public void moveLeft(float leftDistance)
{
    leftDistance = 0.02f;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - leftDistance, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}



public IEnumerator move ()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        moveRight();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        moveLeft();
    }
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    StartCoroutine(move());
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know Unity, but I'm suspicious of a "void" method containing a "yield return".

Comment: When is `i` not less than 10? Move Left is called after a return, therefore never called.

Comment: `StartCoroutine(move());` is called every update? I would start again and maybe not use Coroutines at all.

Comment: Generally when i make an AI script, i split it into - 1.Check condition (where is it, what can it sense), 2.What action to take (shall it move left, stop, go right, fire?)

Answer (score 0):

How do you call `move()`? It needs to be called with `StartCoroutine(move());` to enumerate Unity's `WaitForSeconds`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046749/yield-return-new-waitforseconds2-destroys-function) for a similar problem.

```
while (i < 10)
{
    moveRight();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    moveLeft();
}
```

Additionally, did you forget to increment `i`?